# Extract varbinary column data in its original format

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, extract, bcp

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a `varbinary` column `RelatedData_img` in the table `Reminderimage`. In that column I store Word, Excel files, images (png, bmp or jpg format) or text files etc. Now I want to store data from that column to a disk using command.

I got this command,

```
"bcp "SELECT RelatedData_img FROM Reminderimage.dbo.Reminderimage" queryout reminder.dat -T -c"
```

This command creates a "reminder.dat" file which contains all the data of `RelatedData_img` column. Now I want to extract all the files from that file in its original format (excel, word, jpg etc).

How to extract the `reminder.dat` file ?

Please help me with this.

Comment: You will have to store *additonal information* (metadata) about the file you store in that column, things like **file type**, possibly file name etc. - you cannot extract that information just from the byte stream you're storing - it needs to be handled (stored and retrieved) separately

Comment: @marc_s, Is it not possible to export varbinary contents in bulk ? Because I have more than 1000 such values and writing a script for extracting each files is not a easy one in my case